# Is it possible to remove comment addition when exporting?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

When I do `org-org-export-to-org`, Emacs adds the following comment to the new org file:

```
# Created 2023-12-26 mar. 12:48+
```

Is there a variable that can prevent Emacs from adding this comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single file, add

```org
#+OPTIONS: timestamp:nil
```

To turn it off globally, customize `org-export-time-stamp-file` to nil.

See [Export Settings](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Export-Settings).